# How to put different images next to text in table view controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am coming to a problem where I have put an image for "fastfood" and it shows on all of my text on my table view controller. All I want to show is "fastfood", "Dining", "Service Stations" etc. that will have there own images on a table view controller. I tried implementing it, but I need some help. Can anyone guide me ? Here is my code:

```
class NearMeIndexTitle {
    var indexTitle = String()
    var imageName = String ()
}

class NearMeIndexTableViewController: UITableViewController  {
    var nearMeIndexes = [NearMeIndexTitle]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Table view list  ..
        let nearmeindex1 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        let nearmeindex1Img = NearMeIndexTitle()

        nearmeindex1.indexTitle = "Fast Food"
        nearmeindex1.imageName = "fastfood.png"

        let nearmeindex2 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        nearmeindex2.indexTitle = "Dining"

        let nearmeIndex3 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        nearmeIndex3.indexTitle = "Service Stations"

        let nearmeIndex4 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        nearmeIndex4.indexTitle = "Hospitals "

        let nearmeIndex5 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        nearmeIndex5.indexTitle = "Grocery"

        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeindex1)
        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeindex2)
        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeIndex3)
        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeIndex4)
        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeIndex5)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NearMeIndexCell", for: indexPath) as! NearMeTableViewCell

       let  nearMendexCellValue  = nearMeIndexes[indexPath.row]
       cell.nearMeLabel.text = nearMendexCellValue.indexTitle

       cell.nearMeImageView.image = UIImage(named: nearMendexCellValue.imageName1)

       return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Take what you are doing for the title and do that for the image.

Comment: something like `nearmeindex1.imageName = "fastfood.png"` ? if yes, I tried that already.

Comment: it just does not show. maybe change the format from png to jpg?

Comment: If you're doing the right way and it's not working, post that code. But, try trimming your code down to just the absolute minimum to show what you are doing. We can assume that `numberOfSections` is doing the right think if you don't show it (and you're pretty sure it is ok).

Comment: its the same code above just adding `nearmeindex1.imageName = "fastfood.jpg"`  under my text

Comment: What about the line that currently says `cell.nearMeImageView.image = UIImage(named: "fastfood.png")`. That's the one that is setting the image.

Comment: yes. But, that is just sets to all the text on the table view controller. For example: fast food image shows to all the text on the rows.

Comment: No, that line is setting what image is shown in the cell. It is called for each cell that is shown.

Comment: So, I need to create a for each cell to call my images?

Comment: Change that line so it doesn't have a hard coded image name. Get the name in the same way as you are getting the title.

Comment: when I do `cell.nearMeImageView.image = nearMendexCellValue.imageName1` i get an error: `Cannot assign value of type 'String' to type 'UIImage?'`

Comment: `cell.nearMeImageView.image = UIImage(named: nearMendexCellValue.imageName1)`

Comment: now, it gives me `Value of type 'NearMeIndexTitle' has no member 'imageName1`

Comment: That error doesn't match with the change I suggested, so it is either on another line or you have some something else. Without seeing the code, I can't help you.

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: There's so much code in your question that is not needed but you are missing the definition of NearMeIndexTitle, which is very important. Please add that.

Comment: what you mean as definition of `NearMeIndexTitle`?

Comment: We don't know what `NearMeIndexTitle` is as it is not shown. You use it but it is defined somewhere else.

Comment: so, it wasn't `imageName1` it is actually this `cell.nearMeImageView.image = UIImage(named: nearMendexCellValue.imageName)`

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: I have edited your question to remove all the code that is irrelevant to your problem. Please do this yourself in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the changes made to your code already, you need to set the image names for the other types, where I have marked.

```
class NearMeIndexTableViewController: UITableViewController  {
    var nearMeIndexes = [NearMeIndexTitle]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Table view list  ..
        let nearmeindex1 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        let nearmeindex1Img = NearMeIndexTitle()

        nearmeindex1.indexTitle = "Fast Food"
        nearmeindex1.imageName = "fastfood.png"

        let nearmeindex2 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        nearmeindex2.indexTitle = "Dining"
        nearmeindex2.imageName = "dining.png" // here

        let nearmeIndex3 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        nearmeIndex3.indexTitle = "Service Stations"
        nearmeindex3.imageName = "stations.png" // here

        let nearmeIndex4 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        nearmeIndex4.indexTitle = "Hospitals "
        nearmeindex4.imageName = "hospitals.png" // here

        let nearmeIndex5 = NearMeIndexTitle()
        nearmeIndex5.indexTitle = "Grocery"
        nearmeindex5.imageName = "grocery.png" // here

        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeindex1)
        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeindex2)
        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeIndex3)
        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeIndex4)
        nearMeIndexes.append(nearmeIndex5)

        self.tableView.reloadData()
   }

   override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
       let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NearMeIndexCell", for: indexPath) as! NearMeTableViewCell

       let  nearMendexCellValue  = nearMeIndexes[indexPath.row]
       cell.nearMeLabel.text = nearMendexCellValue.indexTitle

       cell.nearMeImageView.image = UIImage(named: nearMendexCellValue.imageName1)

       return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot for your help @Gary

Comment: you can use struct which will be simpler than class, because it has default constructor

Comment: @Vinodh I agree and there’s many more changes that could be made to be nicer code but I thought it was more important that he could see what was wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Did you add any constraint? I used storyboard and had my picture stand next to labels perfectly.

[image]